# Pyinstaller "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:" when running app

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I recently have packaged a python app using the `pyinstaller --onefile` command. It succesfully makes a executable file that launches fine. I can use pretty much almost all the functions in my script with no problem, except one. When I call a function of another python file (which is in my app folder), I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "socketserver.py", line 647, in process_request_thread
  File "socketserver.py", line 357, in finish_request
  File "socketserver.py", line 717, in __init__
  File "http/server.py", line 426, in handle
  File "http/server.py", line 414, in handle_one_request
  File "CaptchaHarvester/harvester/server/__init__.py", line 134, in do_GET
  File "CaptchaHarvester/harvester/server/__init__.py", line 178, in handel_request
  File "CaptchaHarvester/harvester/server/__init__.py", line 85, in _load_template
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/rl/rmr5s0ld22j0h_z15m90v0c80000gr/T/_MEIBVnHEv/harvester/server/templates/ga.chunk.html'
----------------------------------------
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 54955)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "socketserver.py", line 647, in process_request_thread
  File "socketserver.py", line 357, in finish_request
  File "socketserver.py", line 717, in __init__
  File "http/server.py", line 426, in handle
  File "http/server.py", line 414, in handle_one_request
  File "CaptchaHarvester/harvester/server/__init__.py", line 122, in do_GET
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/rl/rmr5s0ld22j0h_z15m90v0c80000gr/T/_MEIBVnHEv/harvester/server/icon.png'
```

The problem seems to be that pyinstaller cant properly find the files(icon.png and ga.hunk.html). These files are in a folder that is in the same folder as my main.py file. I was wondering how I can make pyinstaller find these files succesfully? I have tried to add to the datas class in the .spec file, but I still get the error. This is what that line looks like:`datas=[('/Users/A/Desktop/ss/CaptchaHarvester/harvester/server/icon.png','/Users/A/Desktop/ss/CaptchaHarvester/harvester/server')],`
Please let me know if I am doing something wrong or if yall have any ideas on how to resolve it.

I am on macosx catalina and python 3.7 if that is any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use arguments in command prompt to ensure the correct filesare found by pyinstaller; `--add-data "path_to_file:path_in_executable in directory"` an example would be

```
pyinstaller --add-data "icon.png;." --onefile socketserver.py
```

here icon.png is in the same directoy of socketserver.py and is copied to the root directory of the executable (the `.` signifies root directory)

Comment: After successfully running that for both my files(gahunk.html and icon.png) I still get the error.